# BASH_REMATCH doesn't capture

Tags: regex, bash, zsh

I'm trying to capture a part of a path in bash:

Input: `/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/venv-test-server`

Code:

```
#!/bin/zsh
regex="^.*\/venv-(.*)$"
if [[ $VIRTUAL_ENV =~ $regex ]] ; then
  echo "Matched!"
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Output: `Matched!`

But the match isn't printed. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The script is specifying `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
       ^^^^
```

If you want to use `zsh`, you need to set `BASH_REMATCH` option before using `=~`:

```
setopt KSH_ARRAYS BASH_REMATCH
```

Comment: setopt did the trick. Thank you. I had to use unsetopt KSH_ARRAYS after the fi, because it otherwise broke my Terminal.

Answer (score 7):

The equivalent array in `zsh` is `match`:

```
% [[ foo_bar =~ (.*)_(.*) ]]
% print $match[1]
foo
% print $match[2]
bar
```

Comment: What version of `zsh` are you using?

Comment: zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)

Comment: You'll need to turn off `BASH_REMATCH`, and use `${match[0]}` and `${match[1]}` if `KSH_ARRAYS` is still enabled.