# Why does BASH_REMATCH return empty when the script file is sourced from zsh?

Tags: regex, bash, zsh, macos-catalina

So I created myself a cute little bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TEXT="FOO BAR"
REGEX="FOO (.+)"

if [[ $TEXT =~ $REGEX ]]; then 
    echo "Matched ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
    echo "No match."
fi
```

Pretty basic. If I run `./cutescript.sh`, then I get the result:

```
Matched BAR
```

But if I source the script, `. ./cutescript.sh`, then it still matches, but `BASH_REMATCH[1` is empty.

Wat.

I'm on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2), executing this in `zsh`, but with the `bash` shebang.

Can anyone explain this irregularity?

Comment: BTW, this is why it's conventional for files that are meant to be sourced (unlike files meant to be executed!) to have a shell-specific extension. If you `. yourscript.bash`, it's a little more clear that it's _only_ meant to be run in bash; whereas something run with `. yourscript.sh` is communicating by the name that it's meant to be compatible with all POSIX-y shells (which zsh isn't, incidentally).

Comment: ...it's the same as how a Python module meant to be loaded as a library has a `.py` extension, but one meant to be run as a script has no extension at all (you run `pip`, not `pip.py`). Loading things as a library -- as `source` / `.` does -- is appropriate only when those things are written for the same language/interpreter you're already running.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thanks for pointing out the difference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, armed with the knowledge that `BASH_REMATCH` doesn't exist natively in `zsh`, I did a little more digging:

This post is actually a duplicate. There's another question here that explains the solution: [BASH_REMATCH doesn't capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695600/bash-rematch-doesnt-capture)

Setting options `KSH_ARRAYS` `BASH_REMATCH` allows `zsh` to emulate `bash`'s regular expression features.

A simple way to make the above script compatible with `zsh` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Ensures that BASH_REMATCH works if called in zsh.
setopt KSH_ARRAYS BASH_REMATCH

TEXT="FOO BAR"
REGEX="FOO (.+)"

if [[ $TEXT =~ $REGEX ]]; then 
    echo "Matched ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
    echo "No match."
fi

unsetopt KSH_ARRAYS BASH_REMATCH
```

Also another related question: [What is the zsh equivalent for $BASH_REMATCH[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030233/what-is-the-zsh-equivalent-for-bash-rematch?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

When you read the file with `.`, it gets executed by whatever shell you're running  - in this case, you said you're in zsh. The name of the `BASH_REMATCH` array is, as the name implies, specific to `bash`; if your shell is zsh, for example, then the matched text in this case would be found in `$match[1]` instead.  And I don't think ksh does true regex matching at all.

Comment: I'd argue that saying that `.` is short for `source` is backwards: `source` (a nonstandard extension) is a longer, more readable name for `.` (the POSIX-standardized, portable name for the operation).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference! Your answer helped me come up with a solution that allows the script to work identically in `zsh`.

Comment: Glad I could help! FWIW, the whole match (bash's `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}`) is found in `$MATCH` in zsh, since arrays like `$match` don't conventionally have an index 0 in zsh.